# OpenGL - Matrix operations

Tags: java, opengl, matrix, 2d, libgdx

Assume I have 2 matrices :

```
MatrixA = translation1 * scale1 * rotation1
MatrixB = translation2 * rotation2 * translation3
```

Is `MatrixA * MatrixB` equals to `translation1 * scale1 * rotation1 * translation2 * rotation2 * translation3` ? Or something else near ?

In fact I just want to know if I can avoid multiplying matrices together and save some CPU by using only 1 matrix and then chain up mathematical operations.

Because I plan to make a little custom 2D engine which would be built upon LibGDX, including a *graphic components API* similar to what you can find in the Android SDK. Anyway there will be some components, those that are in containers, that will need to move when their parents move. So I need these imbricated arithmetic. I know it's possible using matrices but as it is supposed to run on mobile devices I don't want it to be too slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are indeed correct. You can avoid having more than one matrix by multiplying a chain of them together. However, do remember that Matrix Multiplication is **non-commutative** which means that changing the order of the operations will result in two different matrices. For example:

`matrixTranslate * matrixRotate` will result in an object rotating around a point, while:

`matrixRotate * matrixTranslate` will result in an object rotating around its own central axis. No order of multiplying matrices is wrong, however you have to be aware of the different results.

Having said this, in your question:

```
MatrixA = translation1 * scale1 * rotation1
MatrixB = translation2 * rotation2 * translation3
MatrixC = MatrixA * MatrixB
```

This is 5 matrix multiplication operations. If you were to chain them all together:

```
MatrixC = translation1 * scale1 * rotation1 * translation2 * rotation2 * translation3
```

You would also be doing 5 matrix multiplication operations. As you can see, there is no difference in actual operations. You are technically allocating one extra matrix and depending on your implementation and frequency it may make a difference, but in terms of mathematical operations, it is the same.

Comment: So is there a real advantage to use chaining calculation instead of directly multiplying matrices ? Is matrix multiplication that slow ? Does it would be worth it to have such code structure (I mean, for CPU & memory usage on mobiles) ?

Comment: @miNde it definitely saves you operations. In your code above, you perform 7 matrix multiplications in total, while with the chaining you perform 6. I personally always use "chaining" but don't worry too much about it if you aren't seeing performance hits.

Comment: In fact I didn't compared by testing yet. I just wanted to be fixed before starting developing something using that. I don't want to work for nothing, sounds normal :)

Comment: @miNde I'm so sorry, I made a HUGE and ridiculous mistake, I've updated the answer. Its too early in the morning for me to be answering stack overflow questions ;)

Comment: Lol ... no worries. I will test everything out, make some bench and then accept your answer if you are correct. I should have done this myself before asking.